# "Missing value for primary key elementId" when joining on Class Table Inheritance in Doctrine ORM 2

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

When I try to join on an inherited class I get an OutOfBoundsException from Doctrine with the error message above.

I have defined following entities:

FormElement is the parent class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="ETYP_ID", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     1 = "DatetimeElement",
 *     3 = "ChoiceElement",
 *     4 = "TextElement",
 *     5 = "MatrixElement",
 *     6 = "HtmlElement"
 *     })
 * @Table(name="FORMELEMENT")
 */
abstract class Formelement {
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="ELE_ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $elementId;
}
```

ChoiceElement is a child class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="CHOICEELEMENT")
 */
class ChoiceElement extends Formelement {
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="CHOE_ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var Choice[]|ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Choice", mappedBy="choiceElement")
     */
    private $choices;

    public function getChoices(){
        return $this->choices;
    }
}
```

And Choice joins on ChoiceElement

```
/**
 * Class Choice
 * @package apps\dynfrm\models\Doctrine\entities
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="CHOICE")
 */
class Choice {
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="CHO_ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ChoiceElement
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChoiceElement", inversedBy="choices")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CHOE_ID", referencedColumnName="CHOE_ID", nullable=false)
     */
    private $choiceElement;
}
```

`ChoiceElement` is a `FormElement` and has multiple `Choice`s. Everything works fine, even the call to `ChoiceElement::getChoices()`. When I try to access the resulting `ArrayCollection` however, Doctrine throws error mentioned above.
I already did some digging using the debugger, but I don't understand if this is a bug or intended behaviour.

I really hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ChoiceElement` inherits `Formelement`, it does not need to have another id field.

As it is, when doctrine stumbles upon your `ChoiceElement` entity, it will define a composite primary key because two fields are marked with the `@ORM\Id` annotation which is probably not the behaviour you want. Thus, when it tries to join from your `Choice` entity, Doctrine complains because it only has one of the two needed keys that compose the primary key.

To solve this, simply remove the `id` attribute of your `ChoiceElement` entity. Consequently, don't forget to update the `referencedColumnName` attribute of your `choiceElement` association. It should now be `ELE_ID` and not `CHOE_ID`.

---

**Edit:** Quick working example:

<kbd>AbstractA.php</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({1 = "A"})
 */
abstract class AbstractA
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

<kbd>A.php</kbd>

```
/** @ORM\Entity() */
class A extends AbstractA
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a")
     */
    private $bs;
}
```

<kbd>B.php</kbd>

```
/** @ORM\Entity() */
class B
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="bs")
     */
    private $a;
}
```

Outputs the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abstract_a (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, discr INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE a (id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE b (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, a_id INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_71BEEFF93BDE5358 (a_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E8B7BE43BF396750 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES abstract_a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE b ADD CONSTRAINT FK_71BEEFF93BDE5358 FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a (id);
```

And when I am trying to browse the array collection of `B` entities from an `A` entity, Doctrine triggers the following query successfully:

```sql
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.a_id AS a_id_2 FROM b t0 WHERE t0.a_id = ?
```

In the same fashion, it is able to join the `B` table without a fuss if I ask it to. Here is the query performed when I join `a.bs`:

```sql
SELECT a0_.id AS id_0, b1_.id AS id_1, a0_.discr AS discr_2, b1_.a_id AS a_id_3 
FROM a a2_ 
  INNER JOIN abstract_a a0_ ON a2_.id = a0_.id 
  INNER JOIN b b1_ ON a2_.id = b1_.a_id 
WHERE a0_.id = ?
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either. Since in my schema, `FORMELEMENT` and `CHOICEELEMENT` are different tables and `ELE_ID` is the primary key of `FORMELEMENT` and `CHOE_ID` the primary key of `CHOICEELEMENT`, these keys are different. If I try to join `CHOE_ID` on `ELE_ID`, I don't get back any results. Just removing the @Id annotation on Choiceelement did not work either, I still get the same error message.

Comment: That's weird, I have a quite similar case in one of my project and it's working fine. I was not talking about removing the `@Id` annotation but about removing the whole `$id` attribute from `ChoiceElement`. It does not matter if in your schema you have two different tables. Doctrine is clever enough to repeat the primary key defined in your abstract class in the child table. That's how the `JOINED` strategy does its thing. What did you try exactly ?

Comment: @lioxo I added a minimal example that works for me, hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks, your example helped a lot! Unfortunately it still does not to exactly what I am wanting it to do. 

I did as you said and removed the `$id`-Attribute from ChoiceElement and set the `referencedColumnName` in Choice to `ELE_ID`. It now doesn't throw an error, but it also does not return any `Choice`s for any given `ChoiceElement`.

Comment: @lioxo What kind of query are you executing ?

Comment: I'm just using a valid `ChoiceElement`-Entity and call `getChoices()` on it, which should give me an uninitialized `ArrayCollection`. When I initialize the `ArrayCollection` with `$choices->toArray()`  it's still empty.

I created a Gist with my current files and the database schema for reference. You can look at it [here](https://gist.github.com/slioxo/d556f519ab72d9e807956096979fb7fc)

Comment: @lioxo First of all, the `schema.sql` does not seem up to date. There should not be a `ELE_ID` field in `CHOICEELEMENT` anymore. Apart from that, what is the content of the `CHOICEELEMENT` and `CHOICE ` tables ? I tried the exact same request with my A & B entities and my array of Bs was properly hydrated.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the schema and I can't change it. However, I tried recreating the schema and the entities from my minimal example and it surprisingly works. I am now comparing my example code and schema with my actual code and schema to spot differences that could cause the issue. Anyways, thanks for your help!